# Angular/Java: Manage time-based application

Tags: java, angular, timer, cron

I'm developing an application using Angular for front-end and Java RESTful JSON API for backend.

The application allows users to enter information related to yesterday events. And the data entry should be entered between a defined time range: from 00:00 AM until 02:00 PM.

For instance, today is Jan 5:

1. On Jan 5 as of 00:00 AM, the app will allow the user to enter data
   from Jan 5, 00:00 AM until Jan 5, 02:00PM and the user will enter
   only data related to **Jan 4**.
2. On Jan 5, 02:00 PM until Jan 5, 23:59 PM
   PM, the user should not be allowed to enter any data.
3. On Jan 6, 00:00 AM, the user should be able to enter data for Jan 5 only from
   Jan 6, 00:00 AM until Jan 6, 02:00PM and the user will enter only
   data related to **Jan 5**.

So I need to keep track of the date required for data entry (such as Jan 5, Jan 6) and I should handle gate during which the user can enter data (00:00 AM until 23:59 PM)

How do we manage that in Angular/Java? Could you provide some hints please?